# Append incremented number to multiple uploaded images using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Append incremented number to multiple uploaded images using JavaScript

I'm trying to upload multiple images to our  HP Records Manager Database using the ServiceAPI .NET SDK. Written in ASP.NET MVC.

The images upload successfully but they all have the same Title as it uses the same input field.

I want to be able to create a loop that will append an incremented number to the end of the Record Title. (e.g Upload_1, Upload_2, Upload_3....and so on)

```
<form action="Record" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input id="gpsearchtitle" type="text" name="RecordTypedTitle" value="" required="True"/>
<input id="choose" type="file" name="upload" multiple="multiple"/>
<button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Is there a way of appending a incremented number using JavaScript?

**Update**
I have tried doing this:

```
<script>
    function appendNo(){
        var inp = document.getElementById('choose');
        var txt = document.getElementById('gpsearchtitle')
        for (var i = 0; i < inp.files.length;) {
            var name = inp.files.item(i).name;
            txt.value = txt.value + "_" + i;
            i++;
        }}
</script>
```

However, this adds the incremental count to all image Titles. For example if i upload 4 images the Titles show up as, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3, Upload_0_1_2_3

Answer (score 0):

Try grabbing each title (after loading dom elements) and setting them incrementally:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  function pageLoad() { 
    var titles = $('input[name="RecordTypedTitle"]');
    for (t in titles)
    {
        titles[t].val(t);
    }
  } 
</script>
```

Then in body, include the parameter `onload="pageLoad();"`

Comment: I have tried this but, couldn't make it work. Sorry, I'm still quite new to Javascript. Is there a reason why you call the function when the page loads? Wouldnt it be called upon submitting the form?